# What is the difference between kosher dill pickles and Polish dill pickles?

Tags: spices, food-identification, pickling, kosher

What is the difference in taste between kosher dill pickles and polish dill pickles? Do they have any visual distinctions that would make it possible to differentiate between them on sight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are two different processes. Unfortunately English language don't have two words for the outcome and they are both called "pickles".

Usually Polish pickles "kiszony" should be made with: 
cucumbers, dill, fresh horseradish, garlic and salt. No vinegar.
Kosher pickles, called in polish "korniszony", are made with brine that contain vinegar.

I assume that those two recipes have been mixed outside Poland and both things are "korniszony" with the difference that "polish ones" call for ingredients used in "kiszony". The difference in taste is that polish one is much more spicy while kosher one is sweet.

Comment: In the United States, kosher dill pickles, or kosher dills are usually lacto-fermented, i.e. cured in a salt brine, not in vinegar.  They are not sweet, although some of them - the so-called "half sours" are not very sour.

Comment: Lacto-fermented is exactly "kiszony". From what I've seen in such case "kosher" is usually in quotes or the full name is "lacto-fermented kosher dill pickles". In the substance lacto-fermented are softer and the brine is cloudy while kosher pickles are crunchy with clear brine.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google, it would seem that Polish pickles might/would contain more spices.

[From ehow:](https://www.ehow.com/info_12323092_kosher-pickle-vs-polish-pickle.html)

> Due to their similar origin, Polish and kosher dill pickles resemble one another in preparation, making it difficult to distinguish between the two -- that is, until you taste them. While kosher dills are made with garlic, Polish dills are often made with more pickling spices, giving you a zesty, peppery pickle.

[From Our Everyday Life:](https://oureverydaylife.com/kosher-pickle-vs-polish-pickle-40645.html)

> Polish dills contain more spices and garlic than either traditional dill pickles or kosher dill pickles. These pickles tend to be peppery and may be flavored with mustard seeds. Their flavor is similar to the kosher dill and they are served in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Kosher pickles are naturally fermented by the weight of the fruit x 0.02% of salt as similar to Amish style I believe.

Malted vinegar is added to Polish pickles with some sugar. I have seen polish pickles that are naturally fermented too and called sour dill. Generally, Kosher Pickles do not have any added sugar, but in this modern world, the commercial stuff tends to be modified and only the name is used.  If you want the real deal make them yourself it isn't hard.

Oh, and kosher pickles exclusively use Kosher salt too.  I doubt that commercial makers use kosher salt. They would use cheap non-iodized cooking salt.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, the Polish dill pickles are sweeter. That's why I like them. No company in the US makes a sweet Polish Dill pickle. I haunt Polish delis looking for the good stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Polish dill pickle spears are sweeter than kosher pickles. They are not spicier than kosher pickles. Kosher pickles are spicier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).